# My android virtual device doesnt recognize when I update my code

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

My problem is that my Android Virtual Device (AVD) doesnt update when I update my code.

For instance, I run the AVD with my first code. Then I make some changes in the code (removing stuff and adding stuff). But still, the things that are shown on my AVD are from the old code. Stuff that should be there because I removed it from the code are still there when I run my AVD. And of course the new stuff isnt there.

I do:

1. Save my new changes.
2. Restart my AVD

But still it doesnt work.

If I restart my computer the changes might appear... help!

Comment: Did you install the new app on the AVD?

Comment: Have you reset your adb?? and also try go in project option and clean your project

Comment: Install the app? I dont know, the randomness on when it works tells me that something is very strange.

I dont use adb yet. I run my AVD in eclipse. I didnt dare to clean my project. because it says "the project will be rebuilt from scratch", that frightens me haha

Answer (score 1):

What helped me sometimes was deleting the old apk that was saved. For some reason it wasn't running replacing the old apk to be installed on the avd properly.

Also...more info could help. Are you running the code through eclipse/android studio/command line? Is your android application native or running html with the help of phonegap?

Comment: I am running it through eclipse. I wrote the code in eclipse as class documents and xml documents.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to restart the AVD. The thing you have to do is to reinstall yout application. Clicking `Run` in Eclipse will do the job.

Comment: @knixer, if you think my answer helped you, may I ask you to accept it as the correct one :)

Answer (score 0):

I used the wrong API for my development. I used 20 when my book told me 17.
The Target was wrong. Used: "Android 4.4W.2 - API Level 20" but needed to use: "Google APIs (Google Inc.) - API Level 17"
I thought a higher API would be able to handle all lesser API numbers.

I dont know the difference between Targets "Android 4.2.2 - API Level 17" and "Google APIs (Google Inc.) - API Level 17" though.

Anyway all my problems seems to be resolved now.